# how could i pass the key prop to a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, key, styled-components

i have a key prop error that i can't resolve. I guess i should pass the key prop but it does not work. Here is my map function

```
<TableRow key={row.id} sx={{ '&:last-child td, &:last-child th': { border: 0 } }}>
  <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
    <Person lastname={row.lastname} firstname={row.firstname} />
  </TableCell>
  {CalculateHours().map((c) => ( DisplayDate(c, {row}) ))}
</TableRow>
```

And here is my function:

```
const DisplayDate = (c, {row}) => {

if (ParsingTime(row.startDate) > c && ParsingTime(row.startDate) < c+1) {
    return <TableCell key={c} style={cellStyle}><hr style={hrStyle.hr1} width={calculatedWidth(ParsingTime(row.startDate), true)}/></TableCell>
} else if(ParsingTime(row.endDate) > c && ParsingTime(row.endDate) < c+1) {
    return <TableCell key={c} style={cellStyle}><hr style={hrStyle.hr2} width={calculatedWidth(ParsingTime(row.endDate), false)} /></TableCell>
} else if(ParsingTime(row.startDate) > c || ParsingTime(row.endDate) < c+1) {
    return <TableCell key={c} style={cellStyle}><hr style={hrStyle.hr3} /></TableCell>
} else {
    return <TableCell key={c} style={cellStyle}><hr style={hrStyle.hr1} /></TableCell>
}
```

};

How can i pass the key ? Thanks for answers

Comment: How is it doesn't work? What is the error?

Comment: [You can't use the names `key` or `ref` as props.](https://reactjs.org/warnings/special-props.html)

Comment: can you elaborate, which component is this `TableCell`?

Answer (score -1):

The react docs says that the keys should be in sibling objects -> [https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#:~:text=Example%3A%20Incorrect%20Key%20Usage](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#:%7E:text=Example%3A%20Incorrect%20Key%20Usage)

So for your code, it should be in the DisplayDate component when doing the map.